# JQuery: How to display loss screen when timer hits zero

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown">20</div>
```

JS:

```
var doUpdate = function() {
$('#countdown').each(function() {
    var count = parseInt($(this).html());
    if (count !== 0) {
        $(this).html(count - 1);
    }
 });
};

function firstLevel() {

    var interval = setInterval(doUpdate, 1000);

    $("select").change(function() {

    if ( certain selection is selected ) {

        counter++; // add one to the counter

        // if all selections are properly selected
        if (counter === 8 && $countdown.text() > 0) {
            // win condition
        } 

    }

   }); 

    if (counter !== 8 && $countdown.text() === 0) {
       // LOSS CONDITION. PROBLEM HERE
    } 
}
```

So I have 8 divs each with a selection form, the player "wins" if they choose the right option for each selection in a set amount of seconds, and they "lose" if they fail to select all right options in each selection. The timer does not work however. I think it's because in my loss condition, $countdown.text() is only set once and doesn't update as the timer updates. How do I fix this? A solution I came up with is:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $firstlevel.hide(); 
        $gameover.show();
    }, 20000);
```

Which works but it seems like a terrible solution.

EDIT: Nvm it doesn't work. It displays the loss screen after 20 seconds even if you win.

Comment: Why do you need this `$('#countdown').each(function() {...`. `ID` should be unique.

Comment: Ah okay, just made it a class

Comment: You need to paste more code!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `clearInterval();`, `data attributes`, and `.off()` to do this like the below:

#### In the example, quickly select 1,2,3 to win

```js
var $selects = $("select");
var $countdown = $('.countdown');
// start a timer to update the countdown
// but keep a reference to it so we can call clearInterval(interval); later
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
  var count = parseInt($countdown.html());
  if (count !== 0) $countdown.html(count - 1);
  else {
    // countdown ended so the user lost, remove event handlers and stop timer
    $selects.off(); // remove change function
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert('you lost');
  }
}, 1000);

$selects.change(function() {
  // when a select changes, loop over them all
  var won = true;
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val().toString();
    var correct = $this.data('correct').toString();
    // compare selected val to correct val stored as data attribute 
    if (val != correct) {
      won = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (won) { // if all right, user wins, remove event handlers and stop timer
    $selects.off();
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert('you won');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">
  5</div>
<select name="" class="" data-correct="1">
  <option value="select an option">select an option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="" class="" data-correct="2">
  <option value="select an option">select an option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="" class="" data-correct="3">
  <option value="select an option">select an option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```